# property map does not exist on type string | Array<string>

Tags: arrays, typescript, compiler-errors, type-safety

This is how I have defined defined default value in interface , because sometimes it is string and othertimes it is array, I am doing map, when I am sure it will be array. however I get the ts error 2339.

```
interface ABC {
defaultValue?: string | ILabelValue[];
}
// below is my code
x.defaultValue.map(e=>e.value) // I am getting error map does not exist on type string | ILabelValue[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like if we do a type check in the code, then typescript would stop complaining, so I got rid of the error like this.

```
if(x.defaultValue instanceof Array){
  x.defaultValue.map(e=>e.value)
}
```

Now there are no typescript compilation errors for the above code.

so we have to do one more check, however I would also like if there is a way to tell typescript that I know what I am doing and I am sure that over here, defaultValue will always be array.

Comment: The way to tell TypeScript that you know what you are doing is to use `any` or `ts-ignore`. Otherwise, you let TypeScript tell you what to do, like in this case, to be safe.